# Use mutate_if (R dplyr package) or another function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to mutate values in a column conditional upon values in another column. For example, in the mtcars dataset, add 8 to all values in column "gear" only if cyl==6. I tried to use mutate_if from the dplyr package, as below, but no luck. Any suggestions welcome. Thank you.

```
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars %>% mutate_if(mtcars$cyl == 6, gear = gear + 8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mutate` instead of `mutate_if` as there is only one column to change and it is much easier.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
      mutate(gear = case_when(cyl == 6 ~ gear + 8, TRUE ~ gear))
```

---

Also, if there are multiple columns, we can use `mutate_at` and specify the variable of interest

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate_at(vars(gear), list(~ case_when(cyl == 6 ~ . + 8, TRUE ~ .)))
```

---

The use of `mutate_if` is slightly different.  As an example, if we want to change only numeric columns or `factor` columns, then the column as a whole is changed by specifying a logical condition

```
iris %>%
      mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ . + 10))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[cyl == 6, gear := gear + 8]
```